# Accessing subclass members using KeyPath

Tags: swift, swift-keypath

I was trying to access subclass members using `KeyPath` when I encountered something strange. Look at these 2 simple classes:

```
class A {
    var a:String {
        get {
            return "str"
        }
    }
}

class B: A {
    override var a:String {
        get {
            return "str1"
        }
    }

    var c = 10
}
```

Now if I have the following code:

```
var m: A = B()
var k = \B.a
print(m[keyPath: k])
```

I will get a runtime error. It seems that you cannot access to subclass members using a `WriteableKeyPath`. But the following code works:

```
var m: A = B()
var k: AnyKeyPath = \B.a
print(m[keyPath: k]!)
```

I can use this code to access both `\B.a` and `\B.c`. Any idea why it is like this?

Since returned object by using `AnyKeyPath` is immutable, I will not be able to use it for updating object. I wonder if there is any workaround for updating subclass members using a `KeyPath` on parent class or not.

**Update:**

In order to elaborate more, here is another example:

```
var v: UIView = UILabel()
var k = \UILabel.text
v[keyPath: k] = "test" // Error cannot do this
```

I think this can be very useful.

Comment: Is there a special reason not to use `\A.a`  as the key path?

Comment: @MartinR I can use `var k = \A.a` here, but what about `var k = \B.c`? It cannot be used. And I want to know why. Because I think updating `c` should be possible too.

Comment: @MartinR added another example to show why this can be useful.

Comment: But `v` need not be a UILabel. Wouldn't optional casting/chaining be the simpler solution?  E.g. `(m as? B)?.c = 5` or `(v as? UILabel)?.text = "test"`

Comment: @MartinR I like to use keypath to write a function for updating custom class member which is defined by passing through argument. for example something like this: `func updateField(obj: AnyObject, field: KeyPath, value: Any?)`. optional binding can be used in post examples, but I don't know any way for updating fields like this `updateField` method.